# Is there a way to add a unique view to a dynamic field in Display Suite

Tags: display-suite

I am using Display Suite 7.x-2.6 and have created a *Dynamic Field* for my  content-type. I have seven (7) unique items of that content-type. I configured *Full Content* to use "Dynamic Right Column" on the right side of a static two-column layout.

I would like to ***add a unique view for each "Dynamic Right Column"*** Is this possible? OR Should I use a *Custom Code Field* for this kind of functionality instead of *Dynamic Field*?

Using Display Suite Extras *does not* make each of my content-type items unique. I can't add a unique view/block/piece of content to each. I *do not* have Page Manager enabled.